# What does the following sentence mean - "Li is least reactive but the strongest reducing agent among all alkali metals"

Tags: kinetics, reactivity, reduction-potential

Isn't it contrasting? Is reactivity only concerned with kinetics of reaction ?

PS - I am a high school student, probably I might be missing small detail!

Comment: It means that the thermodynamics of reduction are more favorable but the kinetics are less so than with other metals.

Comment: Oh I see it. I guess I was right, thank you very much. Really grateful for your clarification....